# Could not initialize class com.android.build.gradle.internal.TaskManager

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, sdk, build.gradle

I'm new to android app development and cannot resolve these errors:

1. `Could not initialize class com.android.build.gradle.internal.TaskManager`
2. `Unable to load class 'com.android.tools.build.jetifier.processor.Processor'.`

the first error is there when i'm just creating an empty project in the android studio with `gradle version 6.5`, `compileSdkVersion 29`.